# Magento layout and positions

Tags: css, magento, layout, compare, php

I'm trying to do some magento redesign, so i'm a little confused, about two things:

1. How can I add Compare product block to the left column( where, and what i must add) for example i'm using 2columns-left and on left column there is no that block..
2. How to change position of element on product page for example, I want that mine product image goes on right side, and short description below of image, i have confused, where to look up,what files,what code, to change position ?

-I know that i can with css positioning, but it's messy and not ok so much. :/

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you asked here for both point.

1.For compare products app/design/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/layout/catalog.xml. 
Move this line

```
<block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" before="cart_sidebar" 
name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
```

from inside the tag ‘’ inside the tag ‘’
Clear the cache and you’re done.

2.To check your file or block from where it is comes from just go throw this step then you can change your layout or position or product in your magento project

```
goto->admin->system->configuration->Current Configuration Scope(left side)->select main website->Debug(right tab)->Template Path Hints ->select yes->refresh home page
```